# ElasticSearch index contains little data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following problem. I use Laravel and ElasticQuent package for using ElasticSearch in Laravel. My SQL request contains 35 rows and after I added them to the ElasticSearch index, it contains 18 rows only. What's the reason of my problem? Thanks for reply.

Comment: Could you provide the code you are using to index to Elasticsearch

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for replying but I've found the solution by myself. The problem was in ElasticQuent package. It assigns to ElasticSeacrh's index attribute '_id' the value of the DB's field id. My SQL request was with 2 'UNION', so there were several items with similar id's and in ElasticSearch index they stacked, so the quantity of the items in index were different from sql request's rows.